# How to shuffle (completely at random) big data stored in Excel file by Matlab?

Tags: matlab, import-from-excel

I want to shuffle my data row wise (in a single unique row there will be no shuffling, it has to remain the same - I mean all individual cells in a single row can not change). The number of rows I have in my excel files is around 170000.

All I need is to shuffle randomly all the rows among them. How can I do this by mat-lab commands? Codes or algorithm please!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [reading and writing excel files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) see `xlsread` and `xlswrite`.

To [randomly shuffle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) the rows of a matrix:

```
M = magic(5);
Mshuffled = M(randperm(size(M, 1)), :)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, for the tips. 

I am afraid this may not solve my need. The individual data inside each cell can not be modified, it has to be the same. The shuffling is need in a row wise. All the rows (1 to 170000) need to be suffled randomly.

Comment: @MustafaMamun I'm not sure I follow your problem. This code will shuffle all the rows and NOT the columns without changing any of the data

Comment: @ Dan: I am experiencing matlab errors when the number of the rows are many. For example: i used 314258 rows. And matlab is showing errors> " Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded". Additionally matlab also shows magic and meshgrid errors. I have used excell add-ins for this works, but i had to split the dataset in to two, and it takes huge time to randomly shuffle the rows and post processing. 

What to do now with this kind of matlab erros? Could you please help me.

Comment: @MustafaMamun It works for me, but I don't have your data. What do you mean `magic` errors, you shouldn't be using `magic`, that was just an example.

Comment: @ Dan: Thanks dan for your comments. which function i have to use then?


 i tried  Y = randn(size(A));    but it changes the original values of the data. I have 11 colums (parameters) and 314259 rows.

Comment: If you data is in a matrix called `data` then `Shuffled_data = data(randperm(size(data,1)), :)` as I have written above

Comment: @ Dan: Thanks Dan, for your codes. It works for any single column. But my data is in a matrix (11 columns and 314258 rows). How can i convert this m by n matrix into a vector (M). I've provided a snapshot of data in the question.

Comment: @MustafaMamun This code **DEFINITELY** works for a matrix, hence the `,:`. Please make a simple test matrix for yourself and if you still think it doesn't work then post the simple test input and output. But it must be a *simple* test matrix, small and easy to see what is changing.

Comment: @ Dan: I understand your point. Another problem is that the first column consists of string characters (please see the snapshot above in the posted question)and the rest 10 columns includes numeric values only. When i insert them all as Inputdata [for example: Input(11,:) = variable;] matlab cannot include them in a single matrix and shows error [conversion to cell from double is not possible]. How can i solve that error and include string+number as Input (not separately). Because all data in a single row is interlinked and cannot be shuffled colum wise rather it has to be row wise shuffling.

Comment: According to your help and codes, i did a test. And except the first column, the other 10 columns (only numeric values) are shuffled perfectly in a random manner. But i need to shuffle also the first string column (altogether). How can i do that? Could you please help me.


Moreover i need to know which algorithm is being used by Matlab for this random shuffling. Is it Knuth shuffle algorithm or else. Thanks!

Comment: @ Dan: According to the codes (that you provide), this is quite alright, the data have shuffled row wise. My problem is how can i include the first string column into the matrix. matlab is showing error.

Comment: @MustafaMamun This is a completely new question, so ask it as a new question. Look up `cell` matrices first. If you want to know how randperm works internally, google it.

Comment: @ Dan: I have posted a new question. Could you please answer on that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Dan, you can use `xlsread` and `xlswrite` for manipulation of Excel files. You could use `randperm` to achieve shuffling effectively, but another way to achieve this would be using the [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) command.

For example:

```
>> A = randint (5,2,[1,10])

A =

     2     2
    10     5
    10    10
     5     8
     9    10

>> A(randsample(1:size(A,1),size(A,1)),:)

ans =

    10     5
     2     2
     9    10
    10    10
     5     8
```